# What is the use of getWrappedElement() method which is declared in WrapsElement interface and why does only Select class implement it?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am able to understand all the methods implemented in Select class except getWrappedElement() method. Can anyone please help me out on this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is used if you have your WebElement encapsulated in some other entity. There are two examples:

1. `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select` that actually mimics the behavior of [`select`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) control. It implements `WrapsElement` in order to provide the actual element it "decorates" (however it is not a decorator hence I put quotes here).
2. `org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.EventFiringWebElement` which works in pair with `EventFiringWebDriver`. It actually wraps the base element and allow to run actions before and after your element methods call. Hence you might want to obtain that base `WebElement` in some reason which is supported by implementation of `WrapsElement`

In the latter case there is also a code that "consumes" entities implementing `WrapsElement`. Such objects are expected for example in `executeScript` in order to unwrap objects you're passing as parameters for your script.

`WrappedElement` is also used in a number of internal Selenium classes where it tests if an element is the instance of `WrappedElement` and unwraps it before proceed to next steps.